# Python Script not executing in Light Table

Tags: python, lighttable

I made a python script game battleship, but I can't seem to execute it in Light Table. Is it supposed to pop up a terminal running my script?

Here is the script:

[script elided because it works under CPython2.7]

Comment: The script works just fine under Python 2.7 (except there is NameError on vert in find_shot). I suspect there is a problem with the installation of lighttable or — it being alpha code — might just be buggy.

Answer (score 3):

open an existing file foo.py

press the little arrow at the bottom of the screen to show the console (to see output)
in the text editor type

```
print "hello"
```

and press ctrl-enter while still on the same line.

You will see "hello" in the console, which means you are evaluating code

if you press ctrl-shift-enter it will eval the whole file, so if you load up your script can run it this way